# Puxar um retorno de uma função do JS para o C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

No processo de cadastro do usuário quero validar seu CPF pelo JavaScript e retornar se ele é valido ou não no *beckend*. E assim fazer um `if` com esse resultado para inserí-lo no banco de dados ou não.

```
if (ValidaCpf(txtCpf.Text) == False){
    //retorna um erro
}

else{
   //cadastra o usuário
}
```

Obs: Já tenho a função de validar o CPF e o método de Inserir o Usuário no BD. Só preciso passar o resultado da validação do JavaScript para o C#.

Comment: Deixe mais informações. Isso vem de um form? Como ele é criado?

Comment: Você não deve confiar na validação em javascript, você sempre deve revalidar todos os dados no servidor, um usuário mal intencionado pode burlar suas validações em javascript e enviar o que quiser para o servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Esse é um exemplo simples em Jquery para envio do cpf.

```
var cpf = 000000000000 
    $("button").click(function () { 
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: "/Home/PostJson", //local para onde vai ser enviado
                    type: "POST", //forma de envio
                    contentType: "application/json", 
                    data: '{cpf:cpf}', //informação enviada
                    success: function (data) { 
                        alert(data);
                    } 
                }); 
            })
```

Agora olhando no lado da aplicação

```
 public class HomeController : Controller 
    {          
        [HttpPost] 
        public JsonResult PostJson([FromBody] string cpf) 
        { 
           //faz a validação do cpf

           return Json(VarResultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        } 
    }
```

Envia o CPF por JSON para o lado da aplicação, que faz a validação e depois retorna com o resultado para a tela.